# How to put my FloatingActionButton on top of every layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, floating-action-button

I have a `ScrollView` layout and it has a child `constraintLayout`. I made it like this so even in landscape mode, I can scroll through a long text. I am wondering where and how will I put the `FloatingActionButton` so it becomes on top of everything. When I try to add it, the button becomes scrollable too! (which is not a good thing because I want the button to be "floating")

Any suggestions

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="org.cvsuimus.theflare.NewsDetailActivity">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/newsdefault" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textColor="@color/primaryTextColor"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ivImage" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvAuthor"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="Author"
            android:textColor="@color/primaryTextColor"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.073"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvTitle" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvPubDate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:text="Publishing Date"
            android:textColor="@color/primaryTextColor"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.087"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvAuthor" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvContent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:text="tvContent"
            android:textColor="@color/primaryTextColor"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.067"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvPubDate"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
            tools:text="Content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Category"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="Category:"
            android:textColor="@color/primaryTextColor"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tvCategory"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvContent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.692" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvCategory"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="128dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="Category"
            android:textColor="@color/primaryTextColor"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fabFavorite"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/secondaryColor"
            app:fabSize="normal"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.975"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.935"
            app:rippleColor="@color/secondaryLightColor"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: How about putting button outside the scrollview?

Comment: Wrap your ScrollView in an e.g. `CoordinatorLayout` and place the FAB in that layout.

Comment: you can add the fab to the parent view (which is a frame layout) witch contains your activity after you add the main layout this will draw it on top.

Comment: @Mihai I used your suggestion and I made my whole activity a `FrameLayout` and has two children layout which is the `ConstraintLayout` (contains my FAB) and a `ScrollView` (contains my main layout). However, I tried clicking the fab button, it does not ripple. (Because I put a ripple effect on the fab) Is it normal? Is the button still working fine? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: If the fab is clickable it should ripple by default, if it does not work try adding a ripple drawable as the background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it on my own but tried a different approach. I used a `CollapsingToolbarLayout` to be able to use the `fab`. Now it's working smoothly.

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.cvsuimus.theflare.NewsDetailActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivImage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:adjustViewBounds="false"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/bannerplaceholder" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

                <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvId"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:visibility="gone" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                        android:text="Title"
                        android:textColor="@color/primaryTextColor"
                        android:textSize="25sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvAuthor"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                        android:text="Author"
                        android:textColor="@color/primaryTextColor"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.073"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvTitle" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvPubDate"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                        android:text="Publishing Date"
                        android:textColor="@color/primaryTextColor"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.087"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvAuthor" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvContent"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                        android:text="tvContent"
                        android:textColor="@color/primaryTextColor"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.067"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvPubDate"
                        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
                        tools:text="Content" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/Category"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:text="Category:"
                        android:textColor="@color/primaryTextColor"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tvCategory"
                        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
                        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvContent"
                        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.692" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvCategory"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="128dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="128dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:text="Category"
                        android:textColor="@color/primaryTextColor"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

                </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </FrameLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/primaryDarkColor"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/appBar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_bookmark_border_black_24dp" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Relative Layout with your scroll view and FAB inside this RelativeLayout. It would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="org.cvsuimus.theflare.NewsDetailActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivImage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/newsdefault" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="Title"
                android:textColor="@color/primaryTextColor"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ivImage" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvAuthor"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="Author"
                android:textColor="@color/primaryTextColor"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.073"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvTitle" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvPubDate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:text="Publishing Date"
                android:textColor="@color/primaryTextColor"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.087"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvAuthor" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvContent"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                android:text="tvContent"
                android:textColor="@color/primaryTextColor"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.067"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvPubDate"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
                tools:text="Content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Category"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="Category:"
                android:textColor="@color/primaryTextColor"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tvCategory"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvContent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.692" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvCategory"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="128dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="Category"
                android:textColor="@color/primaryTextColor"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabFavorite"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/secondaryColor"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:rippleColor="@color/secondaryLightColor"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I just moved FAB outside. Didn't watch inner elements.